# How to check element type in IOS automation

Tags: ios, automation

How can I check if an element in Element Tree is type of UIASegmentedControl?

For example

scrollView.elements()[i] is type of UIASegmentedControl

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the answer myself.

```
scrollView.elements()[i] instanceof UIASegmentedControl
```